# Keeping references for entities from 2 different Core Data models at the same time

Tags: ios, core-data, entity, nspersistentstore

I have 2 distinct core data models in my iOS app. In the first VC, I create a reference to an entity `UserDetail` in a singleton class I've designed.

After the user leave this VC, I use another core data model, completly different from the first one. I change objectModel, objectContext and persistentStore.

And it seems that after I change to this second core data model I lose the reference to the entity `UserDetail` that I've created in the beginning.

After the fetch I save the reference like this:

```
UserAccount *account = [array objectAtIndex:0];
sharedInstance.account = account;
```

and after changing the core data model whenever I try to access `sharedInstance.account` it's nil. Should the property be (copy)?

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: How are you maintaining a reference to the `UserDetail` object?  Are you caching the properties or setting a reference to the entity?

Comment: After the fetch I save the reference like this: **UserAccount *account = [array objectAtIndex:0];**

then

    sharedInstance.account = account;

and after changing the core data model whenever I try to access sharedInstance.account it+s nil.

Should the property be (copy)?

Comment: Are you sure that you're initializing the singleton before you save something to it and have you check that `account` is non-nil out of the array?  Example: `MySingletonManager *mySingleton = [MySingletonManager sharedManager];`